# zend framework installation on vista

Tags: zend-framework, path, windows-vista

I am doing zen frame work installation by http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html in this i am following the comments of Posted by: alstanto on: 2010-04-07 22:04:18 
I had done all the things added to the path variable c:\zend\library;and php path also and restart the system.this thing work on xp but not working on vista.

but while running `zf show version`  it is saying me that zf is unrecognized command .

please suggest how i can do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same Way Problem was in setting path variable i had given the space before ; :-)